# Unpacking sequences for functions

Tags: python, django

After watching Raymond Hettinger, I decided to go through my code and make it faster and more beautiful. The example given on the slides is, unfortunately, not good enough to get me going (ref. https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/transforming-code-into-beautiful-idiomatic-python-by-raymond-hettinger)

Here's my code. Do you know how I can make it faster? It's from my django code that inserts data from a list.

```
FiveMin(timestamp=datetime.strptime(s[0], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
        station=stat,
        district=s[2],
        fwy=s[3],
        fdir=s[4],
        ftype=s[5],
        length=float_or_zero(s[6]),
        samples=int_or_zero(s[7]),
        p_observed=float_or_zero(s[8]),
        total_flow=int_or_zero(s[9]),
        avg_occupancy=float_or_zero(s[10]),
        avg_speed=float_or_zero(s[11])).save()
```

If not, are there any significant speed losses?

> *Note:* originally hosted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665364/unpacking-sequences-for-functions

Comment: Insufficient context: what is s? where did come from?

Comment: data is downloaded and parsed from a text file (not shown). Code above shows data insertion in django. Is there a faster/more beautiful way to do this using python's sequence unpacking?

Comment: If it is already parsed, why are you doing conversions there?

Comment: Show us the download and parse steps. Then we'll have a better idea of what options are available. Making code beautiful requires looking at more then just one line at a time.

Comment: @codesparkle sorry, by parsed, I meant broken down using a delimiter. Now to save, the db expects a certain format hence the conversions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sequence unpacking instead of numeric indexing:

```
(timestamp, dummy, district, fwy, fdir, ftype, length, samples, 
    p_observed, total_flow, avg_occupancy, avg_speed) = s

FiveMin(timestamp=datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
        station=stat,
        district=district,
        fwy=fwy,
        fdir=fdir,
        ftype=ftype,
        length=float_or_zero(length),
        samples=int_or_zero(samples),
        p_observed=float_or_zero(p_observed),
        total_flow=int_or_zero(total_flow),
        avg_occupancy=float_or_zero(avg_occupancy),
        avg_speed=float_or_zero(avg_speed)).save()
```

This avoids a couple of problems of the indexing approach:

1. It is easy to make the mistake of using a wrong number
2. If you need to add or remove a variable in the middle, you would need to update many numbers, possibly making a mistake.

Unpacking may also be *slightly* faster, but the difference is rather negligible.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough context here to review your code. For example, all those calls to `int_or_zero` and `float_or_zero` look suspicious (Django ought to be able to do that kind of conversion for you if you set up the model correctly), but without being able to see the model definition, or the source code for those functions, or the format of the data in `s`, it's impossible to say whether they are necessary or not.

If you're doing bulk database insertion from a file, then:

1. Use the database's own bulk insertion tool, for example [`COPY` in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-copy.html) or [`LOAD DATA INFILE` in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html).
2. Or, if you must do it via Django's object–relationship mapping engine, use Django's [`bulk_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) method instead of saving objects one at a time.
3. Or, if you must save objects one at a time using Django's `save()` method, then at least do it inside a single transaction instead of a sequence of individual transactions. Use Django's [`@transaction.commit_on_success`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_on_success) decorator (or [`@transaction.atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) in version 1.6).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll change a lot of my code to reflect this.